# Chrome drop text starts with : opens about:blank

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Some time ago i detected a wierd functionality in chrome browser. When you drag a text starting with : from another window to current, then drop it to any empty space (not input or textarea) for some unknown reasons chrome opens about:blank. This function ignores any event like document.ondrop or window.ondrop. Do anybody know how to disable this?

Comment: This behavior seems to stem from the "navigate to URL on URL drop" (e.g., when dropping the text `http://www.example.com`, navigation occurs). This particular case seems like a clear-cut bug, though, since `:foo` is not an intelligible URL, and it certainly shouldn't resolve to `about:blank`. I'd advise [filing a bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list).

Comment: bug reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=253836&can=4&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)